# Can I go to a temple on my Grandma's 10th death anniversary(thidi)?

Tags: temple, death

My dad's mother's death anniversary (thidi) is on this Friday. It's been over 10 years since she passed away. My dad and his older brother are going to do the karma Pooja at home like every year. Can I go to a temple on that day? (I've got an important business)

Comment: Yes you can go ti the temple as there is no Ashaucha